# Make a dynamically generated div droppable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, html, droppable

I am working on a Table with div inside the cell, and I want that div to be droppable.
And when I drop something in a div it generate a new div under the first one.
But the dynamically generated div must be droppable to and now it's not...

Here is the creation of a div:

```
// in a loop with i
divCreate = $("<div>", { id: "divCreate" + i, class: "droppable" });
$(divCreate).css("text-align", "center");
$(divCreate).css("width", "125px");
$(divCreate).css("height", "30px");

$(Cell).append($(divCreate));
```

JS droppable :

```
$(".droppable").droppable( function() {
  // a lots of line with several function
})
```

So I try to add that `$(divCreate).droppable();` to the creation of the div. Now the div is droppable but not with the JS function that I affect to the class ".droppable".

Do I need to make `$(divCreate).live("droppable");` ? Or is it impossible and I need to put all the code from the JS function to the div creation? I really want to avoid that if it is possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the `droppable` code into a named function:

```
function my_droppable() {
    // a lots of line with several function
}
```

And change your general binding to:

```
$(".droppable").droppable(my_droppable);
```

Then you can do:

```
divCreate.droppable(my_droppable);
```

after appending new elements dynamically.

Comment: I think it could work like that but how can I make the drop event with a function? `divCreate.droppable({drop: dropFunction()});`

Comment: It should be `{drop: dropFunction}`

Answer (score 1):

Try to use:

```
$(divCreate).appendTo($(Cell)).droppable();
```

Answer (score 0):

[Here is the sample](http://jsfiddle.net/8qb6C/) I have created.

```
$( "<div/>", {
  "class": "test",
    id:"myDiv",
  text: "Drag me!",
    width:"125",
    height:"30",
    'text-align':"center"
}).appendTo( "#droppable" );

$("#myDiv").css("text-align", "center");

$("#droppable" ).draggable();
```